# How to run a specific JS script without setting up the whole filesystem

Tags: javascript

Guten morgen.

I need to run a specific js script via adding it to a basic html file, so the script would be running as I open index.html (btw, if you know a better way to simply run a specific script with just one click, I'd appreciate to know it).

So, here I have a script that uses FileSync (fs) with:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

But since the "require" method himself requires "require.js', which requires "main.js" (how funny is that) to run properly, i'm getting stuck. So, to run my script.js I need to write another script to make require.js work, but that's not what I was planning to waste my time on.

I'm not a Web-learner and I'm not going to study all the stuff needed, I just need to run a particular JS script.

P.S. Yes, I'm planning to write a proper script on a python, but as I already have a working (not quite right) solution on JS, I want to try it first.

Comment: Never had such problem. I usually just write the script in one file and run it with `node script.js` command (if we assume that file's name is indeed `script.js`).

Comment: Maybe I dont know the easiest way to exec the scripts. Do you just type that in a console from a web browser dev tools or a specific IDE?

Comment: I type that in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

something.js:

```
function hello(){
  alert("Hello");
}
```

index.html:

```
<script src="something.js"></script>
<button onclick="hello()">Clicky</button>
```

of course this is not a well-formed html, but it's okay for a test.
`require` is about handling modules and the like in node.js, in html you have the [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag where you can write code directly or load something from an external source.
Note that if you have node.js code, that won't necessarily work in a browser.

Comment: I got it, its Node.js code, thats why it does not work from CMD with 'node script.js'
Thanks a lot!